# HERE REST API OAuth 2.0 Token Request (with a 1.0 header) Error

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, here-api

I've been trying to get my PHP application to create a successful token request since finally managing to get it working with Postman as per the docs [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/authentication/dev_guide/topics/using-postman.html)

Apparently the API is using OAuth 2.0 which is why I expect to send up `grant_type`, `client_id`, `client_secret` and `expires_in` (if I don't specify one of these fields then the API will successfully tell me it is missing).

Now the problem I am having is with this OAuth 1.0 Authorization Header that I am having to generate, which Postman seems to have no issues doing so, however trying to do it in PHP I am just getting an error returned from the API about a signature mismatch:

```
array:6 [
  "errorId" => "ERROR-fde4f0f1-9d5c-43fd-80eb-056cbf2c3259"
  "httpStatus" => 401
  "errorCode" => 401300
  "message" => "Signature mismatch. Authorization signature or client credential is wrong."
  "error" => "invalid_client"
  "error_description" => "errorCode: '401300'. Signature mismatch. Authorization signature or client credential is wrong."
]
```

I've tried various debugging, a lot of which gives me different errors then I keep landing back on this one so the signature must be the problem.

I created the following class [here](https://gist.github.com/clnt/f629cc71217a822221a03713905f9f7b) to handle generating a header, getting some guidance from the class in the `guzzle/oauth-subscriber` package.

Here is an example of the request headers being generated:

```
array:2 [
  "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  "Authorization" => "OAuth oauth_consumer_key="XXXXXXXXXXXX",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",oauth_timestamp="1583629976",oauth_nonce="Br2HsCVzsaEe3KswBhtCzsSxjUDWgX56",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="G7%2B5f2v2Kdx3rp%2B28DcuJRBvhi9H7fHC1mFLqJIgmMc%3D""
]
```

And the request body:

```
array:4 [
  "grant_type" => "client_credentials"
  "client_id" => "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
  "client_secret" => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  "expires_in" => 87000
]
```

Sensitive details replaced but `consumer_key` is correct and thats the same value as `client_id` and the same goes for `consumer_secret` and `client_secret`

No matter how I try and alter the `signUsingHmac()` method to change the signature, it doesn't work and it all looks fine to me D:

Anyone got any ideas?

If I can get this working nicely I will pull it out into package to make the auth for this API in PHP a lot less painful.

EDIT:

I tried forming the signature exactly like shown in the docs [here](https://developer.here.com/olp/documentation/access_control/topics/error-messages.html) but to unfortunately it still hasn't worked, this is what my `$baseString` looked like when passing into the hash method:

```
POST&https%3A%2F%2Faccount.api.here.com%2Foauth2%2Ftoken&grant_type%3Dclient_credentials%26oauth_consumer_key%3DXXbXbXbXbXbXbXb%26oauth_nonce%3DrZNNSZGOOIHFFtLboCjdAheCmKJmOYSp%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA256%26oauth_timestamp%3D1583640503%26oauth_version%3D1.0
```

I've also created a new gist [here](https://gist.github.com/clnt/0d74367effadeac3cd34f6c7ac8a06e6) with my updates to create this `$baseString`

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: Updated [gist here](https://gist.github.com/clnt/cf7451d4cbabe80c53ffbfbe15dc66cb) with latest changes, only sending `grant_type` in body now but same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a gist that works.
Some suggestion:

- all values need to be urlenconde()
- the string that you need to use
  for signign the request needs to include: method (uppercase) & URL
  (urlecode) & list of parameters (url encoded)
- the signing key is your consumer key secret (urlencode) **followed by &**. This because usually your signing key needs to me consumer secret & secret token. In this case we don't have secret token

For the list of parameters for your signature base string you need to include all oauth_ parameter and your grant_type because you need to include also the body parameter. The sorting of these keys is crucial

some code PHP code:

```
$keyId = getenv('HERE_API_KEY_ID');
$keySecret = getenv('HERE_API_KEY_SECRET');

$httpBody = [
    "grant_type" => "client_credentials"
];
$httpMethod = "POST";
$httpUrl = 'https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token';


$oauthNonce = mt_rand();
$oauthTimestamp = time();
$oauthSignatureMethod= "HMAC-SHA256";
$oauthVersion = "1.0";


$baseString = $httpMethod."&". urlencode($httpUrl);

$oauth1Param = [
    'oauth_consumer_key' => $keyId,
    'oauth_signature_method' => $oauthSignatureMethod,
    'oauth_timestamp' => $oauthTimestamp,
    'oauth_nonce' => $oauthNonce,
    'oauth_version' => $oauthVersion
];


$paramString =

        "grant_type=client_credentials&".
        "oauth_consumer_key=". urlencode($oauth1Param['oauth_consumer_key']).
        "&oauth_nonce=". urlencode($oauth1Param['oauth_nonce']).
        "&oauth_signature_method=". urlencode($oauth1Param['oauth_signature_method']).
        "&oauth_timestamp=". urlencode($oauth1Param['oauth_timestamp']).
//        "&oauth_token=".
        "&oauth_version=". urlencode($oauth1Param['oauth_version'])
;

echo $paramString.PHP_EOL;
$baseString = $baseString . "&" . urlencode($paramString);
echo $baseString . PHP_EOL;
$signingKey= urlencode($keySecret) . "&";
$signature = urlencode(
    base64_encode(
    hash_hmac(
        'sha256',
        $baseString,
        $signingKey,
        true
    )
    )
);

$oauth1Param['oauth_signature']  =  $signature;
echo "RUNTIME SIGNATURE : " . $signature .PHP_EOL;
```

I create a GIST that works, the only thing that you need to change is $keyId and $keySecret.
https://gist.github.com/roberto-butti/736c38c796ede70c719f6a21a752c971

This documentation was very useful: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/oauth-1-0a/creating-a-signature

Answer (score 0):

It seems the access_id and access_key both are getting passed in the request body, `"grant_type" => "client_credentials"` only needs to be in the body, while `access_id and access_key` should be passed in header. you can try first that in postman, if it does work out, please revert

Comment: If I remove the `client_id`, `client_secret` or `expires_in` from the body in Postman I get the same error I am getting above, "Signature mismatch".

I've also had instances of your API telling me that the `client_id` and `client_secret` are missing from the body, but for some reason I now cannot reproduce.

However by specifying all of this in the body along with the Auth header in Postman I get a successful access token back.

I would expect to send these credentials in the body for OAuth 2.0 client credentials grant, why is there even an OAuth 1.0 Authorization header required?

Comment: I created a new Postman request, following the docs exactly and it gave me back an access token. But so does my other request when I am sending the additional data in the body. 

I've followed through this creating a signature docs tonight [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/authentication/dev_guide/topics/using-aaa-javasdk-or-3rd-party-libraries.html) `baseString` is ok and removed the extra data from body, only supplying the `grant_type` and headers. I'm still getting the same error. I cannot find any PHP libs using OAuth for your api they all use `api_id` and `app_code`.