# Curl returns error signature mistmatch in php via HERE API

Tags: php, here-api

Am working with HERE API using php curl,

Here am trying to get HERE API token  by following their documentation  below[documentation link](https://developer.here.com/documentation/authentication-authorization/dev_guide/topics/request-constructing.html)

```
//sample request
POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: account.api.here.com
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="1tqA_sample1fLhs2z6_q1l",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",oauth_timestamp="1512072698",oauth_nonce="ZGAaMP",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="Q0sample4lqICrx19%2F4ahaH%2Fi2O0NgqDUQJgti5U3Q%3D"
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 
grant_type=client_credentials
```

I have followed the sample request example by when I  run my code below it throws error

```
{"errorId":"ERROR-5e9aeefb-1182-4b80-954c-eed971ee2c90","httpStatus":401,"errorCode":401300,"message":"Signature mismatch. Authorization signature or client credential is wrong.","error":"invalid_client","error_description":"errorCode: '401300'. Signature mismatch. Authorization signature or client credential is wrong."}
```

here is there working sample in nodejs
[working sample in nodejs](https://developer.here.com/tutorials/how-to-authenticate-with-here-oauth/)

below is my code

```
$url2="https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token";
$ch2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_URL, $url2);



//$post_add = "grant_type=client_credentials";
$post_add=array('grant_type'=> 'client_credentials');
$access_key_id ="my access id ke y goes here";
$timer = time();

// perform signature hashing
$signature  = hash_hmac('sha256', $timer, $access_key_id);



curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
"Host: account.api.here.com",
"Cache-Control: no-cache",
"Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key='$access_key_id',oauth_signature_method='HMAC-SHA256',oauth_timestamp='$timer',oauth_nonce='ZGAaMP',oauth_version='1.0',oauth_signature='$signature'",
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
));  

//curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'GET');
curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'POST');

//curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'DELETE');
curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_add);
curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response2 = curl_exec($ch2);

curl_close($ch2);

print_r($response2);
```

Comment: Did you replace the sample access key and signature in the request with your own?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me Anatoly. The main issue is creating the signature on the fly. The API do not specify the parameters needed to hash the signature but from the nodejs sample link in the post. it seems they are hashing the access key and access secret and then converting it to base64. see https://developer.here.com/tutorials/how-to-authenticate-with-here-oauth/     am just confused though I will try different way

Comment: @Anatoly I have hashed the key id and secret and then convert it to base64.   it now throws error **Invalid Client Authorization header, expecting signed request format.**  I think the issue now line in this line of code below. ~"Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key='$access_key_id',oauth_signature_method='HMAC-SHA256',oauth_timestamp='$timer',oauth_nonce='ZGAaMP',oauth_version='1.0',oauth_signature='$signature'",~ can you help me. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60584192/here-rest-api-oauth-2-0-token-request-with-a-1-0-header-error

Comment: Thanks.the link works. You can update it as an answer.

Comment: To recap, please check this converation as answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60584192/here-rest-api-oauth-2-0-token-request-with-a-1-0-header-error